# Plotting a function with 2D vector entry in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following function to plot:

```
f(x) = 3 + (x - (2  6)T )T · (x - (2  6)T)
```

where `(2 6)` is a vector, `T` represents transpose and `x` is a vector of size 2. My question is how can I implement a `np.linspace` so that I can get a continuous 2D function?

I have written my function in the following form:

```
def f(x):
    a = np.array([[2],[6]])
    t = lambda x: 3 + np.dot((x - (a)).T, (x - a))
    return t(x)

x = np.array([[4],[1]]) # Some random (2,1) sized vector
y = f(x) # Returns an array sized (1,1)
```

For example, to plot a variation of the function `f(x) = x^2 (x-squared)` I can write the following code:

```
def f(x):
   return x**2

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 20)
y = f(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

I want to know whether it is possible to plot a continuous function for a case where `x` input is two-dimensional vector. If it is not feasible, how the first function should be plotted? A 3-D plot is not possible since my function only has `x` as its parameter.

`Edit`:

Comment: Can you provide results for your function for an example vector `x`?

Comment: I have slightly updated my question. Hopefully, it is a bit clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@deeenizka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65372664/14277722) is right that we have to plot 3 dimensions. One way to do it is to use a [contour line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line) plot.

First we have to [vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) your function to compute the values of the function with an array of 2D vectors

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    a = np.array([[2],[6]])
    x = x - a
    return 3 + np.einsum('ij,ij->j',x ,x)
```

To get the input coordinate vectors we can use [`meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) and [`ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) the 2D arrays to pass them to the function `f`

```py
x = np.linspace(-50, 50, 100)
y = np.linspace(-50, 50, 100)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
data = np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()])
```

We can plot the data with [`contourf`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html) after we reshaped the returned array of function values.

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.contourf(X, Y, f(data).reshape(X.shape), levels=20)
plt.colorbar();
```

Out:

[image: contour of your function]

Comment: Thanks very much! That's what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Dimension of your vectors is 2. You also have value of function for this vector. In total you have 3 parametrs, so I think it can't be plotted as 2D plot and you need to use 3D plot.(Your `x` vector is just a tuple, so you can use x[0] and x[1] as axis)

Comment: I am not sure how to implement that. My function only has only a x input parameter and it should have the same size as a vector (2 6). If you can think of a way to plot a function as a 3D, can you please share that?

Comment: your function gets vetctor of size 2, so there is two variables: first element of your vector and the second one. You can rename it to `x` and `y` if you want

Comment: You can read about 3D surfaces [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html)

Comment: Got it, Thanks for your help!